# How to manually find discrete-time LQR gains using Algebraic Riccati Equation / Hamiltonian?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

For a **continuous-time** optimal feedback controller, I'm manually computing LQR gains using the Algebraic Riccati Equation, using the Hamiltonian method.

This seems to works fine, as I compare to gains that Matlab produces using lqr(sys, Q, R).

How would this Hamiltonian method be modified to find the discrete-time gains?

Here's what I use for the continuous-time computation, for a system with dynamic matrices A, B, and LQR's Q and R penalty matrices (from standard linear formulation x. = Ax + Bu):

**1)**    `H = [A, -B*inv(R)*B' ; -Q, -A']`

where ' is the transpose.

**2)** Find eigenvalues of H with negative real parts -- stable eigs, say called *lambda* -- and use pole placement to find the gains:

```
K = acker(A, B, lambda)
```

These gains seem to match outputs from Matlab's lqr commands, for example lqr(sys, Q, R).

How do I modify this method to find gains for a discrete-time system?
I tried a few modifications of the above, by using discrete-time matrices and only looking at eigs < 1 (unit circle), but the results that don't match Matlab's results.

**Note 1**: I did not modify Q, R when I tried the discrete-time version: i used the cont-time version, as that's what would be used in both continuous and discrete versions if using matlab's lqr() function.

**Note 2**: there are NO discrete eigs of the Hamiltonian that are strictly < 1, as for some reason they are marginally above 1, eg 1 + 1e-5. However the eigs of the discretized sys matrix A are indeed stable (<1). **So, I believe I might not be building up the discrete H correctly.**

Comment: You will find all you need in the book, "Matrix Riccati Equations in Control and Systems Theory" by Hisham Abou-Kandil, Gerhard Freiling, Vlad Ionescu, and Gerhard Jank.

Comment: Pole placement does not have a unique solution when one has multiple inputs. But one can still use the eigendecomposition of the Hamiltonian to solve the Riccati equation and thus the LQR state feedback gain, for example [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation#Solution). That page also mentions the relevant algebraic Riccati equation for discrete time and how to solve it, using a symplectic matrix instead of a hamiltonian matrix.

Comment: Thanks @KBS. That looks like a good book, but it's $170.

Comment: Thanks @KwinvanderVeen. That does indeed looks like the discrete analog of the Hamiltonian I was using, but it's not clear how to do the decomposition: in the continuous case, it was taking the eigs and using pole placement, but DARE seems to require a decomposition. What would be the equivalent approach to the continuous case? Just take the eigs of the symplectic matrix, and do pole placement as before? "Pole placement does not have a unique solution when one has multiple inputs. " Agreed. I have one input, in this case.